# React Accessing a value from an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, forms, input, jsx

I have a form in React which dynamically adds new input elements. This seems to be working ok but I cant seem to access the input values as shown in this screenshot...

[image: console.log array]

I have tried the following

console.log(this.state.telephone.name)

and...

console.log(this.state.telephone.tidx.name)

where tidx is the unique key.

Here is the constructor...

```
 constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            role: "Installer",
            name: "",
            telephoneType: [{ name: "" }],
            telephone: [{ name: "" }],
            tidx: "",
            emailType: [{ email: "" }],
            email: [{ email: "" }],
            eidx: "",
            notes: ""
        };
    }
```

and this is my function to handle the input forms...

```
handleTelephoneChange = tidx => evt => {

        const newTelephone = this.state.telephone.map((telephone, tsidx) => {

            if (tidx !== tsidx) return telephone;
            return { ...telephone, name: evt.target.value };
        });
        this.setState({ telephone: newTelephone }, () => {
            // get state on callback
            console.log(this.state)
            console.log(this.state.telephone.name)
            console.log(this.state.telephone.tidx.name)
        }
        );
    };
```

and rendered like this...

```
{this.state.telephone.map((telephone, tidx) => (
<MDBRow key={tidx} className="grey-text flex-nowrap align-items-center no-gutters my-2">
<MDBCol md="12">
<input value={telephone.name} onChange={this.handleTelephoneChange(tidx)}placeholder={`Telephone No. #${tidx + 1}`} className="form-control"/>
</MDBCol>
    </MDBRow>
     ))}
```

Any advice greatly appreciated as I am fairly new to forms in React.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`telephone` is an array, so you should be using index notation.

```
  console.log(this.state.telephone[tidx].name)
```

To render a corresponding phone-type for each telephone:

```
{this.state.telephone.map((telephone, tidx) => (
     <MDBRow key={tidx} className="grey-text flex-nowrap align-items-center no-gutters my-2">
        <MDBCol md="12">
            <input value={this.state.telephoneType[tidx].yourValue} onChange={this.defineYourTelephoneTypeEventHandler(tidx)}/>
            <input value={telephone.name} onChange={this.handleTelephoneChange(tidx)}placeholder={`Telephone No. #${tidx + 1}`} className="form-control"/>
        </MDBCol>
      </MDBRow>
 ))}
```

Comment: Thats great thanks the index notation worked. I cant type anything in the input field if I use your event-handler suggestion..

Comment: @StevenCollins nice glad that first part worked for you. That's interesting, and you're not experiencing any issues with the UI with your initial code?

Comment: thats correct, it all worked ok previously. here is a quick video with my original event-handler https://www.screencast.com/t/pQOPVLff

Comment: I hope you dont mind another quick question related to my post which has been bugging me. I have another imput field called TelephoneType.  Is it possible to do something like this or would they need to be seperate? {this.state.telephone.map((telephone, tidx, telephoneType, ttidx) => ()}

Comment: @StevenCollins you can not do that within your existing `this.state.telephone.map()`, that function strictly follows this argument structure. `array.map((item, index, ownArray))` so you would not be able to a directly target your other array like that. However, if we assume that the order of the items in `telephone` arr correspond to the same order of items in `telephoneType`, you could just use the index of provided  the first array to reach into the value of 2nd array. Similarly you would use index notation :)... Otherwise, you can just use a second `.map()` as well

Comment: Telephone and TelephoneType need to be returned together for each row if that makes sense. https://www.screencast.com/t/CN3EssEK0p I may need to open a new post for this..

Comment: I did try with a separate .map() but it was breaking the UI. Ill give it another go. Thanks.

Comment: See my updated solution above, also note you do need to create an event-handler for the phone-type as well.

Comment: yes I already have that but as its a select/dropdown its a bit more tricky https://www.screencast.com/t/InaZf0CgWs I do like a challenge haha

Comment: I have finally got this working now with your updated code above.  Thanks. https://www.screencast.com/t/D2KQ8iIDsy