# Applying HTML formatting to React this.setstate

Tags: html, reactjs, state

I have an event handler which updates state when a button is clicked which then renders the state to the page.  The way this is rendered is not correct and is breaking my UI. My question is, Is it possible to apply formatting directly to the following event handler?

I have attempted to create a nested array so only 1 state is updated but no joy.

see this video for formatting issue I am having: https://www.screencast.com/t/HksUkk7g3G

I have also posted previously about this with the full code here.
[React Nested Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56807902/react-nested-array)

```
handleAddTelephone = () => {
    this.setState({
        telephoneType: this.state.telephoneType.concat([{ name: "" }]),
        telephone: this.state.telephone.concat([{ name: "" }])

    });
};
```

I need to format each state update.  Something like...

```
handleAddTelephone = () => {
    this.setState({
        <span>telephoneType: this.state.telephoneType.concat([{ name: "" }])</span>,
        <span>telephone: this.state.telephone.concat([{ name: "" }])</span>

    });
};
```

This is my render function. The call to state needs to be around the MDBRow (Bootstrap row class).  JSX will not allow this and Im currently using 2 separate calls, one for telephoneType and another for telephone.

```
<MDBRow className="grey-text no-gutters my-2">

                                        {this.state.telephoneType.map((tt, ttidx) => (

                                            <MDBCol key={ttidx} md="4" className="mr-2">
                                                <select
                                                    defaultValue={tt.name}
                                                    onChange={this.handleTelephoneTypeChange(ttidx)}
                                                    className="browser-default custom-select">
                                                    <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
                                                    <option value="Landline">Landline</option>
                                                    <option value="Work">Work</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </MDBCol>
                                        ))}

                                        {this.state.telephone.map((tn, tnidx) => (

                                            <MDBCol key={tnidx} md="7" className="d-flex align-items-center">
                                                <input                                              
                                                    value={tn.name}
                                                    onChange={this.handleTelephoneChange(tnidx)}
                                                    placeholder={`Telephone No. #${tnidx + 1}`}
                                                    className="form-control"
                                                />
                                                <MDBIcon icon="minus-circle"
                                                    className="mr-0 ml-2 red-text"
                                                    onClick={this.handleRemoveTelephone(tnidx)} />
                                            </MDBCol>

                                        ))}

                                    </MDBRow>
```

and the button...

```
  <div className="btn-add" onClick={this.handleAddTelephone}>
                                        <MDBIcon className="mr-1" icon="plus-square" />Add Telephone</div>
                                    <br />
```

and array...

```
class InstallerAdd extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            role: "Installer",
            name: "",
/*             telephone: {
                type: [{ name: "" }],
                number: [{ name: "" }]
              }, */
            telephoneType: [{ name: "" }],
            telephone: [{ name: "" }],
            emailType: [{ email: "" }],
            email: [{ email: "" }]
        };
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep JSX objects in your state? The normal solution would be to keep the actual data, which are the basis for rendering, in state, and then only generate JSX in your `render` function.

Comment: Also, your notation seems off.

Comment: @fjc ive updated my code with the JSX Im using. Hope this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @fjc the problem I have is that when I run handleAddTelephone function, the 2 separate states arent getting rendered correctly in the UI.  I need to have one state wrapped around the entire row and im not sure of the best way to approach this.

Comment: I have got this working now. Solution on my other post for those interested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56805133/react-accessing-a-value-from-an-array